# Graphics in command-line Mathematica 7?

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

How do I make command-line Mathematica 7 display graphics?

In older versions of Mathematica, "Plot[x,{x,1,2}]" would popup a 
window displaying the plot w/ some formatting options (line thickness, 
equal xy scaling, etc).

Mathematica 6 and up don't do this. According to 
http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/Mathematica.html most of the graphics 
code is now in the notebook interface, not the command-line interface.

The page above also suggests `"<<JavaGraphicsX"` as a hack (where X is the backtick character which I can't seem to enter here). This works, 
but the graphics window has no options, and, when I resize the window, 
the graph doesn't resize.

Is there a better solution?

My attempt to load Motif.m sadly fails:

```
In[1]:= <<Motif` 

StringForm::sfr:  
   Item 0 requested in "The Motif` graphics package is obsolete, loading 
      JavaGraphics`." out of range; 0 items available. 
Motif::obslt: The Motif` graphics package is obsolete, loading JavaGraphics`. 
 -- Java graphics initialized --
```

Following 
[Debugging a working program on Mathematica 5 with Mathematica 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675626/debugging-a-working-program-on-mathematica-5-with-mathematica-7) I tried loading Version5`Graphics but that didn't really help either.

```
In[1]:= << Version5`Graphics` 
 -- PostScript to stdout graphics initialized --  

In[2]:= Plot[x,{x,1,2}] 
%! 
%%Creator: Mathematica 
%%AspectRatio: .61803 
MathPictureStart 
/Mabs {  
Mgmatrix idtransform 
Mtmatrix dtransform 
} bind def 

[bunch of Postscript crap] 

% End of Graphics 
MathPictureEnd 

Out[2]= -Graphics-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ok with getting the graphics as files instead of pop-up windows, you can use [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Export.html):

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]    
gfx = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}];
Export["sinplot.pdf", gfx]
```

You should of course replace `NotebookDirectory` with something that makes sense outside the notebook context. You can use `Show` to combine Graphics objects, set ranges and viewpoints, etc.

Comment: To make this work well for interactive use, you should find a non-blocking pdf viewer that automatically updates when the file changes. I think almost anything other than Adobe's offering will do -- including many excellent free and/or open source viewers.

Comment: Actually, I already wrote this function: '(* hack for display bug *)
showit := Module[{}, 
Export["/tmp/math.jpg",%, ImageSize->{800,600}]; Run["display /tmp/math.jpg&"]]', which works fine, but, again, there's an extra step after -Graphics- and image manipulation is limited. I think the PDF would also be limited. I realize I can use Show to rotate/resize objects, etc, but it'd be nice to do it interactively.

Comment: Ok. Guess this doesn't help much then. I assume you are running into this because you have the kernel running on a remote machine? Have you considered, and do you have the necessary license, to connect through a local front-end which could handle the graphics?

Comment: My Mathematica's installed locally, but I dislike the Notebook interface and find it clumsy. I have a strong preference for "vt100" style programs vs "graphics" programs.

Comment: :) I see -- so you want GUI for graphics only. I am not sure Wolfram has that in their list of use cases... Have you tried Wolfram Workbench? It is quite nice for working with a combination of ascii only .m files and notebooks.

Comment: Rats, it's not free for registered Mathematica users. Oh well, your answers have been very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you need to specify java grahics:

```
 <<JavaGraphics`
 Plot[PLOT OPTIONS]
```

Comment: I think that was in my original question, though?